# "День как день"

Tags: члены-предложения

В сочетаниях "День как день", "хватит так хватит" и т. п.  чем являются слова "день", "хватит"? Оба подлежащие и сказуемые?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для целей синтаксического разбора эти конструкции рассматриваются как неделимая группа, которая может заменять существительное в любой его роли.  В частности - в роли главного члена односоставного (номинативного) предложения. 
У составных частей в этом случае нет самостоятельной синтаксической роли.

Comment: То есть сочетания "день так день" - подлежащее, а "хватит так хватит" - сказуемое?

Comment: Нет. И то и другое - просто главный член. Или просто подлежащее. Сказуемого в номинативном предложении нет.